# Is it possible to obtain the path of a blocked threat in Windows Defender?

Tags: windows, security, virus, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

Windows Defender notified about a threat that has been blocked, and it provides the type of "threat", but it won't show any information regarding the file, even if I allow the threat.

I have an idea of what it could be, but I need to be sure before taking any action; I checked the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Threats, and any subkey, but it shows no value entries. Checking the History.log file in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Service results in some keys, not sure what they're about, but they do not match with the basename of any file in the subdirectories in DetectionHistory. However, they do have the same format (for example, CD5AF584-5CDA-43D6-94E3-4A84763AB48A), and their content always mentions Magic Version 1.2, the behavior of the threat, the tracking ID, the process ID, the tracking start time, and it also references the NT Authority System. Among the lines, "Unknown" can be found as well.

Does anyone know how to obtain the file path of the alleged threat? Some other questions mention inexistent viruses, but I wonder if this is actually part of that "bug".

Comment: In Windows Defender, where it says that the thread is blocked, quarantened etc, it will show the file path too.

Comment: It will also usually show (or enough information to know) the App and you usually can find the path with that as well.

Comment: It's weird, what I get is the Detected Behavior, Status: Removed, and a generic "A threat or app was removed from this device.". It shows two affected items referenced by a pid, however I can't obtain the pid of the "threat" process if it is not running, thing that WD seems to be blocking... Sorry, forgot to mention, I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Hmm, now it's getting worse. I tried to allow the threat and check those "keys" via FRST, but when I allow the threat it just does nothing, as when I go to to "allowed threats" it always says "No threats.", and then the threat is still there when I go back to blocked threats. It didn't happen 'till I opened FRST. The pid's of the last threat history (can't find any new one), interestingly, match with those of Chrome and Edge. Well, I guess I can't do anything new, since no new threats are found (WD was spamming a lot of notifications about them, at first. Anyway, thanks a lot to you all!

Comment: I got many false positives in pid blocks from defender yesterday, updated defender and they went away, why I assumed they were false positives, no path for them either.

Comment: @Moab I got it fixed even without an update... This kind of bug is really curious, it makes me wonder if it's not the virus itself that masks its existence within a PID of a process related to an executable that apparently doesn't exist. But nah, very unlikely, since it's a new install in my case. But well, Windows itself is a virus...